# dataset.clip is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I took Modis burnt area monthly 500m resolution data. For this data I am applying clip operation and its showing

> clip is not a function

My code:

```
var dataset1=ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD64A1")
             .select('BurnDate')
             .filterDate('2019-03-01','2019-03-31')
             .filterBounds(table)

var burnedAreaVis = {
      min: 30.0,
      max: 341.0,
      palette: ['4e0400', '951003', 'c61503', 'ff1901'],}
    var image=dataset1.clip(table)
    Map.addLayer(image,burndeAreaVis,'2019')
```

Answer (score 1):

After filtering the `ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD64A1")`, you are left with more than 1 image. Hence the variable `dataset1` is not an `ee.Image`; instead it is an `ee.ImageCollection`.

I suggest you make this small change and your code should work.

```
var image=dataset1.first().clip(table)
```

However, you may need to rethink what you wish to do with the variable `dataset1`. You may wish to further filter it, or create a mean/median composite etc.